# Some new products are omitted from the SOLR index

Tags: reindex, magento-1.14, solr

I have a serious problem with **Magento 1.14** using **SOLR**. From this week, for no apparent reason, all new products that are created or updated, they are visible without problem in frontend in its categories. However, when you search the same products in searcher, the site returns that no result was found.

I run reindex of **catalogsearch_fulltext** several times, but the result was the same, no change. I tried going to the SOLR admin and making the query in solr directly, but the result was the same; the products were not found.

One thing I noticed is that, though I reindex or new products are added, if I run the query:

> *:*

This always return to me the numFound as 6300. Likewise, if I go to stats.jsp in solr admin, I see that numDocs and maxdoc have the same value, 6300​​:

> numDocs : 6300 maxDoc : 6300

But thery do not change, they remain constant. I do not know if it has anything to do with this problem.

What can be the source of this?

Comment: Weirdly I have this same issue on 1.14, if I manually create them and reindex nothing gets added to the index. However if I use Magmi to create them, then these get added. Are we just being daft and missing something? I have tired Simple and Configurable products.